# Integral $\int y\,e^{x^2}\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

$$\int y\,e^{x^2}\,dy$$

I begin with

$$\int e^{x^2}y\, dy$$

let $u=e^x$, $du=e^x\, dx$

how do I continue?

Comment: $\int y e^{x^2} dy = \frac{y^2}{2} e^{x^2} + C$
unless I'm missing some unspoken relationship between $y$ and $x$

Comment: So what is the relationship, if any, between $x$ and $y$? I mean why have you put the $e^{x^2}$ inside the integral?

Comment: In case of $y$ is $x$, then you can use substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: IF it is not said, there is no relationship to be assumed

Answer (score 9):

Your integral depend of $y$ **only**, then you can put $e^{x^2}$ out of your integral.

$$\int ye^{x^2}\mathrm{d}y=e^{x^2}\int y\mathrm{d}y=e^{x^2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}+C\right)$$ where $C$ is a constant.